# Как скрыть товары из определенной категории woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой!

Есть категории товаров: Parent Category -> Subcategory -> Child subcategory

В этом виде товары из **Child subcategory** отображаются в родительских категориях. Как сделать так, чтобы товары из **Child subcategory** отображались только при входе в этот раздел? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо скорректировать основной запрос WooCommerce с помощью хука `woocommerce_product_query`:

```
/**
 * Хук в основной запрос WooCommerce для запрета вывода дочерних категорий.
 *
 * @param WP_Query $q WooCommerce query.
 */
function woocommerce_product_query_action( $q ) {
    $tax_query = $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $q->query_vars['product_cat'],
        'include_children' => false,
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woocommerce_product_query_action' );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я так понимаю это настройка будет работать для всех категории в магазине, а можно ведь сделать так, чтобы эта функция касалась исключительно для раздела Child subcategory?
То есть в других разделах чтобы эта функция не выполнялась.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса можно сделать вывод, что child category - это дочерняя категория (любая). Я так и ответил.

Comment: Думаю, надо переформулировать задачу в новом вопросе. Потому что данная связка вопрос-ответ может представлять интерес другим пользователям, которые интересуются, как убрать **любые** подкатегории из выдачи.